# Run CPU-intensive code without delaying UIViewController segue? How to execute code *only once and after* the UIViewController has presented itself?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

Tapping a button in ViewController1 segues the app to ViewController2.

Tapping the button also triggers a slightly CPU-intensive operation. (i.e., merging several images and writing the result to disk). This operation cannot get initiated until the button is tapped.

The side-effect is a poor user experience. The ViewController1 button stays highlighted a beat longer, and the segue is noticeably delayed.

Moving the intensive code to ViewController2's `viewDidLoad` function seems unhelpful since it will produce a delay, but on ViewController2's side not ViewController1.

Moving the code to  ViewController2's `viewDidAppear` also seems undesirable since this operation should only get fired once, not every time ViewController2 appears. Adding a variable just to track whether the operation has fired seems suboptimal.

Another option is to put the code in ViewController2's `viewDidLoad`, but introduce a slight delay with `dispatch_after`, ensuring the code doesn't compromise the segue.

What's the right approach to handle this pattern?

Is there another UIViewController function that should get used for this purpose (i.e., code to execute only once, and only after the UIViewController has presented itself to the user)?

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, here's a thought:

1. Make a singleton class that has your "result" as a property.  When view controller 2 asks for it, the singleton can create it (the result) if it doesn't already exist (if it DOES exist, well, you're already done).
2. Push that long running job into an operation queue and let the operation send a delegate message (or notification, whatever floats your boat) back to view controller 2 when it's done.  When VC2 gets that message, it can "refresh".
3. Depending on how long that job takes, you may want to put in a spinner and/or loading message on VC2 and then get rid of it during the "refresh".

(I mentioned operation queue, mostly because I like them.  It can be whatever mechanism you like, the point being that the work is not done on the main thread.)